# Trigger loginwindow to reload AskForPassword on wake from sleep

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In OS X, there's a preference for requiring a password on wakeup from sleep or screensaver, stored in the preferences domain **com.apple.screensaver**, key **askForPassword**.  I'd like to change that preference from a daemon running as root, but I'm not sure what the right way to do that is.

One option is reading, updating, and synchronizing via [NSUserDefaults persistentDomainForName:].  That successfully updates the preference, however loginwindow doesn't reload that preference immediately.  It's possible to signal loginwindow to reload the preference from an app running in the user bootstrap namespace via this code:

```
CFMessagePortRef port = CFMessagePortCreateRemote(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("com.apple.loginwindow.notify"));
CFMessagePortSendRequest(port, 500, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
CFRelease(port);
```

but the loginwindow port is not available from the daemon's bootstrap namespace.

Is there a better way to update that preference?  Or a straightforward way to signal any loginwindow from the daemon?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this. Any help anyone has on where to even look would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for an answer to this too and have come up short.
However I did find that if you use Apple Script, the values are updated:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set require password to wake of security preferences to false'
```